# Docker running problem on a project using Windows 10 ,version 2004

Tags: docker

[image]

**ERROR:**

> failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessBaseLayer \?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\7fc71f0548706244b490a4c6f442b5ef1caf4ccc8db51580153db20583d55110: The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Please replace your console output screenshot with the relevant commands and error only.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the volumes, was solved by running

`docker system prune --volumes -a`

and restarting the docker service

This removes all the volumes so you might lose data, keep that in mind before running the command